# implementing read/write file_operations in a pci device driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am writing a `pci driver` for a `PCIe FPGA` card.

I am not sure how to implement the "read" and "write" functions - How to use the arguments: 
`struct file *filp, char _ _user *buff, size_t count, loff_t *offp`, correctly in order to do reads and writes to pci memory space.

Can you give me examples of how to use these functions, along with an example of using open/release as well.

Comment: You can refer to this source https://github.com/pkumarg/scull . It has implementation of `read()` and `write()` calls with example in test file.

Answer (score 3):

[LDD3](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch03.pdf) includes a sample character driver "scull" which implements file operations (including read and write) on a memory area. Should be easy to adapt it for your purposes.

Comment: and how can it be adapted for pci. Just few words. I am looking for. What I have in mind is just use pci_dev but how to associate file ops with this struct since no member that looks like can be used.